# PHP is not writing to file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to pass a variable ( n ) from a JS script to PHP thru the URL and get it to write said variable to a file. Unfortunately I can see the PHP script being called over the network, with the appropriate URL and with 200 status, but it doesn't seem to be executing. The file it should be writing to never changes. The disk is not full, the file is not in use by another process and the file it is writing to has completely open permissions as a testing measure. Hopefully this is a simple fix, thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$my_file='count.txt';
$count= $_GET['n'];
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $count);
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Examples of requests being sent

[image]

Comment: Have you tried writing a standard string to the file? Where does the file reside in relation to your script? It's possible that you've not referenced the file correctly.

Comment: Do a `var_dump(realpath($my_file));` and see if the path to the file is correct. I can also recommend using the function: `file_put_contents($my_file, $count);` for writing files. It turns three lines of code into one.

Comment: After `<?php` add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` and then run your code again. check in console for possible errors

Comment: Have you tried with `file_put_contents`?

Comment: So, any updates on this, or have you left the computer/question?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, I was doing this late at night and had to sleep. Count.txt is in the same directory as the html file and php file. file_put_contents does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine and its writing whatever value for n is passed. however it keeps on overwriting previous value for every new request.

```
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w');
```

In 'w' mode it create new file for read and write while placing pointer at the beginning.

Use 'w+' mode this places the pointer at the end of file.

```
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w+');
```

For more details on files you can check below url for different modes and other functions
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: The point of the code was actually to overwrite the value each time. So by all means that is working properly. The problem is that the value never actually changes

Comment: Ok so it must be on my end then. To be clear, can I see your .htaccess?

Comment: i never added any .htaccess file.

Comment: No idea what's up then. Thanks for helping, I'll try and troubleshoot this another time